# Скомпилированная игра Unity зависает!

Tags: unity3d

Скомпилированная игра зависает при выходе. На ошибки в скриптах Unity не жаловался. Проблема именно уже в собранном проекте. Пробовал локализовать проблему, добавил самый минимум на сцену. Оставил персонажа и задний фон, постепенно начал добавлять чтобы появилась проблема. При добавление монет на сцену случилась та же проблема, но при следующем запуске стало все нормально и проблема воспроизводилась через раз. Выхожу из игры, то зависает, то все нормально. Много чего убрал и добавлял в проект, следил за всем, но это не помогло найти ошибку, как будто при выходе зависает рандомно, нет никакой четкой последовательности. Не могу разобраться в чем проблема? Если это проблема в коде, тогда почему в самой unity при запуске все нормально? Теперь зависания происходят на всех уровнях при выходе. Бывало загружаю уровень и сразу выхожу, то все нормально, то зависает. Скинул игру на другой компьютер, делаю одновременно одни и те же действия, на одном зависает, а на другом нет. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: ну вас в коде ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте локализовать проблему. Создайте пустой проект и добавьте туда самый минимум, чтобы проблема воспроизвелась. Если разберетесь, напишите ответ, если нет, включите пример в вопрос. Так навксидку сложно что-то сказать.